# Batch detect text in images

Tags: images, batch

Is there a tool that can batch detect text/watermarks in images and the move them to a separte folder or alert the user in some way?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software. There is an [online version which is free](http://www.free-ocr.com/) you could sample to see how it would meet your needs.

For a more robust approach you could look at leveraging [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list) which should allow for a more batching approach and is sponsored by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but worth a try: there is [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/).